# 2 decimal places on an Nvarchar column

Tags: sql

First of all, I am developing in Microsoft Visual Studio IDE. So, what I am trying to get is a result of a query which the column is an **nvarchar datatype**. The goal of this query is at some point give to the user the percentage of how many different extensions are in the database. 
To explain you guys better I will post it here:

```
SELECT Filetype AS 'Extensão', 
COUNT(*) AS 'Nº de ficheiros',
((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS 'Percentagem (%)',
SUM(Filesize) AS 'Total(KB)'
FROM infofile  
GROUP BY Filetype
UNION ALL
SELECT '---------------',
COUNT('Nº de extensões'),
((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile)), 
SUM(Filesize)
FROM infofile
```

So, what I am trying to get with this line of my query `((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS 'Percentagem (%)'` is a result but just with 2 decimal places and each row of this column. The I have a line `((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile))` that give me the total of the percentage that should be 100 but that displays me 100.00000.

Here it is the output that I'm getting right now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do a `CAST` to convert the `NVARCHAR` to `DECIMAL`:

```
SELECT Filetype AS 'Extensão', 
       COUNT(*) AS 'Nº de ficheiros',
       CASE WHEN (COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile) = 100.0
            THEN '100'
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile))) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
       END AS 'Percentagem (%)',
       SUM(Filesize) AS 'Total(KB)'
FROM infofile
...
```

Comment: Is it that what I really what, but after the UNION ALL I have result that gives me the total in percentage(100.00). It isn't possible to get here just 100 without decimals?

Comment: I will give you an answer but it is going to be ugly :-(

Comment: Why? What's the problem?

Comment: doesn't change anything , keep getting 100.00

Comment: @Rekcs Please mark correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You  can use Format function

```
Format((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile),'0.##') AS 'Percentagem (%)',
```

Comment: But this is the line that I want to format ((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile))

Comment: You can put your expression inside Format function. Something like:
Format( X ,'0.##')
where X is your expression. It will return formatted string with optional 2 digits after point.

Comment: I think I've understood